# How does IEDriverServer.exe and Chromedriver.exe works?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have following questions regarding seleniumn webdriver:

1. How does IEDriverServer.exe and Chromedriver. exe works. i.e. What happens when these exes are executed.
2. What is the significance of using these exes

Answer (score 0):

These executables are used to run the webdrivers. These need to be specified in the System.setProperty. This is something that needs to be done for IE and Chrome but not for Firefox.

Running the .exe by themselves will probably do nothing.

Example Java Code for ChromeDriver:

**System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/.../chromedriver.exe");**

**WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();**

**driver.get(URL);**